# How to include child component while writing unit test cases in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component which has a child component while writing unit test cases I am getting an error saying child component is not defined.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add more details to your question, like the part of code that raises the error and more detailed error message.

Comment: Add Child compoent in import  of spec file and also inside declarations block of TestBed.configureTestingModule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably include child component in your parent component and use it in the declaration. Also add below line
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';